# Retrieve and Display from views.py to template file python Django

Tags: django

How do I retrieve data from the database into views.py and then send it to an HTML file to be displayed?
Example:

- i have a table Average in models.py
- by using Average.objects.filter(condition) in views.py in a function def avg()
- i will be able to retrieve the data and store it in a variable
- how will i proceed from here in sending this data to a html file (student.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use generic views https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/ or make your own:

```
def index(request):
   return render(request, 'student.html', {'query': Average.objects.filter(condition) })
```

I think it would be good to read this https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/